# Java-EE SSE chat

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, server-sent-events

Im trying to make a simple chat where the users connected to the server send a message and the other users receive it.

This is my html:

```
 <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <body>
     <script>
       function setupEventSource() {
         var output = document.getElementById("output");
         if (typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
           var msg = document.getElementById("textID").value;
           var source = new EventSource("TestServlet?msg=" + msg);
           source.onmessage = function(event) {
             output.innerHTML += event.data + "<br>";
           };

           source.addEventListener('close', function(event) {
             alert("Source closed!");
             source.close();
             }, false);
         } else {
           output.innerHTML = "Sorry, Server-Sent Event is not supported in your browser";
         }
         return false;
       }
     </script>

     <h2>Simple SSE Echo Demo</h2>
     <div>
       <input type="text" id="textID" name="message" value="Hello World">
       <input type="button" id="sendID" value="Send" onclick="setupEventSource()"/>
     </div>
     <hr/>
     <div id="output"></div>
   </body>
 </html>
```

And also this inside a servlets processRequest:

```
    // set content type
    response.setContentType("text/event-stream");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    String msg = request.getParameter("msg");

    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

    // send SSE
    writer.write("data: " + msg + "\n\n");
    writer.write("event: close\n");
    writer.flush();
```

Few things I dont understand: if I dont send an `event: close` the browser will keep spamming the message every 3 seconds, why is this? I tried avoiding this by closing the `EventSource` but is this correct? Once the EventSource is closed, you cant open it like just closed, right?

Also I wanted that all the "connected clients" received the message, but this doesnt happen, isnt the `data:` supposed to be sent to all clients?

I have tried with chrome and firefox opend and sending messages, i noticed something about firefox: the message will keep spamming every 6 seconds dispite that I sent the `event: close` after each message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you closing the request in your servlet?  A SSE request on the server needs to be processed differently:

Standard Servlet:

1. Request arrives from client
2. Server creates a response
3. Server sends response back to the client
4. Server closes the connection

With SSE the typical flow is a little different.  First, you typically have to workflows, the servlet workflow, which handles registration of connections, and the event workflow which handles sending events to registered listeners.

Servlet Workflow:

1. Request arrives from client (with type event-stream)
2. Server caches the connection in memory
3. Server does not close the connection

Event Workflow:

1. Something happens to trigger an event
2. Server grabs the cache of connections
3. For each connection still open, server writes the event

My guess is that what is happening is that, when you get an event-stream request you are writing out the events you have at that time and then closing the connection.  This triggers the EventSource on the client side to think it was disconnected or erroneously closed and after 3 seconds it tries to re-register with the server and the whole process happens again.

One other point to note.  If you are using servlets you will almost certainly need to use the asynchronous servlets API otherwise you will have an open thread for every single connected client.

Comment: using a `Servlet`, how do you know that the client has closed the EventSource connection? Thanks,